# Using .htacces to redirect /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using .htaccess to permanently redirect a number of obsolete URL's to new pages on a site.  I've also successfully set up `http://www.example.com/index.html` to `301` redirect to `http:/www.example.com` using:

```
# RewriteRule ^index\\.html$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [L,R=301]
```

However, I also need to redirect `http://www.example.com/`

Specifically "/"?  Everything I've tried so far either causes server errors, or renders the site unavailable (a loop perhaps)?

So my question is simply, how do you go about redirecting `http://www.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com`

Comment: `example.com/` and `example.com` are in fact the same thing, despite what you might be seeing in the browser's address bar. The trailing slash is present in the request, regardless of whether the browser shows it or not. See this related question on Pro Webmasters: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser/35646#35646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, the path in an URL for a http request must always start with a forward slash if you link to domain name with `http://`.

From [Wikipedia - Uniform Resource Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax):

> The path must begin with a single slash (`/`) if an **authority part** was present, and may also if one was not, but must not begin with a double slash.

And if we lookup what "authority part" means, the following information applies:

> - An optional authentication section of a user name and password, separated by a colon, followed by an at symbol (`@`)
> - A "host", consisting of either a registered name (including but not limited to a hostname), or an IP address. IPv4 addresses must be in dot-decimal notation, and IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in brackets (`[ ]`). For URIs relating to resources on the World Wide Web, some web browsers allow ".0" portions of dot-decimal notation to be dropped and even raw integer IP addresses to be used.
> - An optional port number, separated from the hostname by a colon

So if a browser requests an url of say google.com, it will always request it with a forward slash appended.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response, and thorough answer.  Very, very much appreciated.  

I wonder then, WHY I am being asked by a SEO/Marketing agency to do this for a clients site, if it can not be achieved?